# how can i prevent to insert data in database when there is duplicate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is my php code that will put the inserted data to database and will prevent to insert data if there is duplicate.

```
include('session.php');

$cid="";
$chat_name=$_POST['chatname'];
$chat_password=$_POST['chatpass'];
$sql3="SELECT * FROM chatroom where chat_name='$chat_name'";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($query) == 1){
        echo("<script>alert('ee');</script>");
    }

        else{
mysqli_query($conn,"insert into chatroom (chat_name, chat_password, date_created, userid) values ('$chat_name', '$chat_password', NOW(), '".$_SESSION['id']."')");
$cid=mysqli_insert_id($conn);

mysqli_query($conn,"insert into chat_member (chatroomid, userid) values ('$cid', '".$_SESSION['id']."')");
    echo $cid;
        }
```

this is jquery code

```
$(document).on('click', '#addchatroom', function(){
    chatname=$('#chat_name').val();
    chatpass=$('#chat_password').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"add_chatroom.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                chatname: chatname,
                chatpass: chatpass,
            },
            success:function(data){
            window.location.href='chat.php';
            }
        });

});
```

When I enter a duplicate data the alert in echo don't execute but it continue to put in database although it is duplicate. THANKS FOR THE HELP !

Comment: change if statement to `if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)`

Comment: Reference the "alert in echo don't execute": You should make a choice: 1. redirect the user to `chat.php` OR 2. try to execute a JavaScript `alert()`. Next, you cannot accomplish 2 without acting on the return from the server. You send back `<script>alert('ee');</script>`, the AJAX success handler assigns that to the `data` function parameter but then you do nothing with `data`. So pick one or the other and reframe your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, I would change

`if(mysqli_affected_rows($query) == 1){`

to

`if(mysqli_affected_rows($query) >= 1){`

this will make sure that even if there are already duplicates, no more duplicates can be added

**There are however some bigger issues with the code that you should address**

1. You should add a uniqueness constraint on your chatname (in the database). This will make it that even if your code is wrong, you will not be able to add duplicate entries to your table.
2. You are receiving user input and just adding it into your sql querys. This leaves your database open to SQL injection which basically means, anyone can do anything to your database (delete things, add things, etc.). You should look into prepared statements to solve this issue